# MY php form not working ie not sending data to my page

Tags: php, html, css, forms

So i have a php form(a file input form ) as such:

```
<?php $val=$_POST['FORM']?>
```

```
     element.style {
}

 button.punch {

border-top: 1px solid ;
border-right: 1px solid rgb(0,210,50);
border-bottom: 1px solid #151e33;
border-left: 1px solid #1f2d4d;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px 1px green, 0 1px 0 green, 0 6px 0 green, 0 8px 4px 1px green;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px 1px green, 0 1px 0 green, 0 6px 0 green, 0 8px 4px 1px #111111;
color: #fff;
font: bold 20px/1 "helvetica neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 10px 0 12px 0;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #1e2d4d;

-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

```
<html>
<br><br><br>
<div style="text-align:center;box-shadow:2px 2px 2px 2px #999;padding-bottom:50%;margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%;">


<p label for='file'><label for="file"><button width="400%" style="width:100%;height:15%;background-color:rgb(0,255,128)" class="punch"><font size="13%" color="white"><label for="file">Choose file</label></font></button></label></p>
<br><br>

<div style="box-shadow:2px 2px 2px 2px #999;padding-bottom:70%;margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;">
<br>
<?php $val=$_POST['FORM']?>
<?php echo $val?>
Public name

</div>
<form action="uploadtrying1.php" METHOD ="POST"><input id="file" name="file" type="file" style="display:non;" name="FORM"><input type="submit"></form>
</div>


</html>
```

What is supposed to happen is that when the user clicks the big green 'choose file' button,and a file is chosen,the result is sent to the same page and a php script echoes the file chosen by the user...

**BUT ITS NOT WORKING**

Sorry incase the code is a bit confusing let me explain:

- The large green button is the label for the `input type="file"`such that when it is clicked the computer's file manager pops up for somebody to choose a file when the file is chosen,the real input file="type"shows the name of the file chosen
- The submit button beside it onclicked,is meant to post the file name to **THE SAME PAGE** so that the name of the file shows beside the big green button

Comment: `<p label for='file'><label for="file">` - Is just wrong, why are you nesting `label` in the the `p`? Also, the `p` tags doesn't have a `for` property.

Comment: `<?php $val=$_POST['FORM']?>
<?php echo $val?>` - You don't need to open and close the tags for every statement.

Comment: `<input id="file" name="file" type="file" style="display:non;" name="FORM">` Two `name` attributes there. And `display:non;` is faulty

Comment: er...ok but is that affecting it???

Comment: I would read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php), then [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uploading a file use in your form tag.

```
 enctype="multipart/form-data"


<form action="uploadtrying1.php" METHOD ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="file"   type="file"  name="FORM"><input type="submit"></form>
```

and get your file by $_FILES in your uploadtrying1.php file.

Comment: That is *a* problem, not the *only* problem. You should also expand on "why".

Comment: are you have removed  name="file",  attribute in input filed?

Comment: eM..no the result is now"array" when i try to post an image

Comment: Actually tell me what you want to do?

Comment: see this url:
http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Single-File-Upload-With-PHP

Comment: are you got the solution?